# Django jquery datatable: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm trying to load data to jquery datatable from server in django 1.8.1. At the end of the process I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" javascript error.

View;

```
datas = Datas.objects.all()
jsonData = serializers.serialize('json', datas)
return HttpResponse(jsonData, content_type='application/json')
```

In the "Network" of browser it is seen that it returns json array like this;

```
[{"fields": {"objectname": "O1"}, "model": "my_app.datas", "pk": 1}]
```

Html;

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="id_dataTable" style="cursor: pointer;">
</table>
```

Js;

```
  $('#id_dataTable').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": '/getData/',
        "aoColumns": [
            {'mData': 'fields.objectname'}
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "aTargets": [0],
                "sTitle": "Object",
                "sClass": "align-center"
            }
        ],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bPaginate": false
    });
```

Can you help ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the doumentation for jQuery DataTables:
https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

You need to supply you data in the following format:

```
[
    {
    "name":    "Tiger Nixon",
    "position":   "System Architect",
    "salary":    "$3,120",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office":    "Edinburgh",
    "extn":    "5421"
    },
    {...}
]
```

You can iterate over datas in you views to build the objects, append them to an array and then send the Response via JsonResponse:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

datas = Datas.objects.all()
arr = []
for data in datas:
    arr.append({
        'key1': data.key1,
        'key1': data.key1,
    })
return JsonResponse(arr, safe=True)
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer. It was really helpful.  I changed some parts. If it is done via JsonResponse, JsonResponse 
requires a dictionary and i also aranged javascript for this response.

Comment: JsonResponse can also be a list in Python/Django. Will become an array in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

View;

```
datas= Datas.objects.all()
            dataArray = []
            for store in datas:
                dataArray.append({
                    'objectname':data.objectname
                })

return JsonResponse({'data':dataArray}, safe=True)
```

Js;

```
$('#id_dataTable').dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": '/getData/',
            "aoColumns": [
                {'mData': 'objectname'}
            ],
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {
                    "aTargets": [0],
                    "sTitle": "Object",
                    "sClass": "align-center"
                }
            ],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bPaginate": false
        });
```

Here is an answer..